# Change button on close event of popup

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on a button I'd like a popup to open and when I click the accept button in the popup the popup closes. But when it closes, I want to change the button on which the user clicked to open the popup. I have used images instead of buttons. Please advise how can i do it.

Its not working for me.I think you dont get my question."I am clicking on image then popup window opens after accepting whaterver in that popup window again it will show previous window,then that image should change" what should I do for that? Iam sending you updated code here:

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['typeimagedis']=='image/gif') 
        $namedis=$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis'];
        else
    $namedis=$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis'];


    if ($_POST['hidcropimg'] == 'hidcropimg')
{
if(file_exists('images/'.$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis']))
{
unlink('images/'.$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis']);
}
    $targ_w =$_POST['w'];$targ_h = $_POST['h'];
    $jpeg_quality = 20;

if(($_POST['typeimage'] == "image/gif"))
    {
    $src='upload/'.$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis'];
    $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
    }
    if(($_POST['typeimage'] == "image/jpg")|| ($_POST['typeimage'] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_POST['typeimage'] == "image/pjpeg"))
    {
    $src='upload/'.$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis'];
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    }


    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    @imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
$yes=1;
if(($_POST['typeimage'] == "image/gif"))
    {
    $name=$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis'];
        imagegif($dst_r,'images/'.$name,$jpeg_quality);
    }
    if(($_POST['typeimage'] == "image/jpg")|| ($_POST['typeimage'] == "image/jpeg") || ($_POST['typeimage'] == "image/pjpeg"))
    {
    $name=$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis'];
        imagejpeg($dst_r,'images/'.$name,$jpeg_quality);
    }

}

    if($_POST['subacc']=='Accept')
    {
    copy('images/'.$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis'],'crop/'.$_SESSION['typeimagenamedis']);
    setcookie ("cronimagename", $_SESSION['typeimagenamedis'], time()+60*60*24*30,'/','iphoneid.com');}
    ?>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function closewin(){  
    window.close();
    $('#openimg',opener.document).attr('src','/v/vspfiles/photoutility/images/clickheretoTHK_off.gif');
    //alert('openimg');
    }
    </script>

<?php   

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />
        <? if($_GET['ref']==1){?>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://serverl.iphoneid.com/demos/croped.php?ProductCode=<?=$_GET['ProductCode']?>">
<? }?>


    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="outer">
    <div class="jcExample" style="width: 802px;height: 1344px;">
    <table width="151" align="center" style="padding-right:65px;" > 
      <tr><td width="54"><form id="frmacc" name="frmacc" method="post" action=""><input type="submit" id="subacc" name="subacc" value="Accept" onClick="closewin();"  /></form></td><td width="238">
    <form id="frmcancel" name="frmcancel" method="post" action="crop.php?ref=1&ProductCode=<?=$_GET['ProductCode']?>" ><input type="submit" id="subcancel" name="subcancel" value="Select Again"  /></form></td></tr></table>
    <div class="article" style="position:relative; margin:70px 0 0 230px;">
<? if($_GET['ref']==1){
?>
<img  src="wait.gif" width="200px" height="75px"  >
<?
}else{ ?>
        <div style="float:left; height:530px; padding:0px 0 0 0px; width:580px;  background:url(<? if($_GET['ProductCode']=='IPBB'){?>black.png<? }elseif($_GET['ProductCode']=='IPBR'){?>red.png<? }elseif($_GET['ProductCode']=='IPBW'){?>white.png<? }?>) no-repeat; position:relative; z-index:999999999999">

        </div><!--style="padding-top:<?=$padding?>px"-->
        <div align="center"   style=" height: 148px; width: 148px; position:absolute; top:161px; left:61px; z-index:1" ><img  src="images/<?=$namedis?>" height="148" width="148" /></div>
<? }?>
    </div>
   </div>

    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you link a jsfiddle of your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the background image of your button from the pop up window use this :

```
<script>
$("#openimg1",opener.document).attr("src","/image-path-here");
</script>
```

Comment: it means the window from which your popup window got opened.

Comment: Hello, did that answer helped you at all.

Comment: Which source I have to include in this src?

Comment: the path of the image which you want to change after accepting whatever in the popup as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: thank you its working.but I want to add this script in php page,but it gives 
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'...so can you please change it??so that I can easily add it into php page?

Comment: Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay, please show me your code because i don't think so that it can't work with php. it is simple jquery which works well with php. please show me the code.

Comment: I have sent you edited code of php,in that code I have added script which you given.please see closewin() function from that code.It gives error to "opener.document".

Comment: I have updated my existing code plz see above code,that is in php.

Comment: Why did you put all the code above html tag, just try to put it in head section and see if it works.